# Mysterious artifacts in my strain gauge data. Can anyone suggest a possible source?

Tags: noise, interference, strain-gage

I'm working on a project where we are collecting timeseries data from multiple strain gauges.  We are seeing a strange pattern of artifacts in our data.

The artifacts appear as sharp 'spikes' with a duration of approx 0.5sec, which occur at intervals of roughly: 5.5, 5.5, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 60.0, 60.0 seconds apart.

The pattern hits all of our sensors at the same time, suggesting perhaps EM interference?  Also the pattern is non-overlapping, which, to me, suggests a single source.

The entire pattern repeats after a delay of approx 60 seconds continuously throughout the timeseries data.  There are tens of thousands of these polluting my datasets!

From these timings, can any one suggest what type of equipment might be producing this signal?

Notes: The timeseries in question were collected a few years ago, and no we can't shield everything and collect cleaner data.

Another thing which may be relevant is that the facility where the strain gauges are installed is near a marsec facility.

And sorry the sensors were installed long ago, so I have few details on the circuitry and the wiring .  I do know that the gauges are connected to wheatstone bridges, amplified and each is collected by a separate raspberry-pi machine.

The fact that the same artifacts show up on in the data collected  by multiple different SOCs, to me rules out that the signal comes from the power supply or is otherwise a specific to the SOC collecting the data.

I will do my best to provide further details in the chat.

Comment: Just remove the spikes with an algorithm, I've cleaned up hundreds of times series streams. How bad do you need to preserve data?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've removed them already.  I just want to know what they are.

Comment: How about a circuit diagram and a picture of the test setup

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that this stuff was installed a few years back.  I only have high level information on the hardware installation which I described in the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly from a [weather radar scan](https://www.radartutorial.eu/15.weather/wr07.en.html). Here is one scan strategy- they change the antenna rotational speed during the cycle in a way that bears some resemblance to your observations:

12°/s = 30 seconds per rotation

18°/s = 20 seconds per rotation

30°/s = 12 seconds per rotation

> Scanning strategy A scanning strategy is shown in Figure 4. A cycle
> starts with a precipitation scan, whose antenna tilt depends on the
> coverage angle (horizon) of the radar site. During this rotation, the
> radar works with a pulse repetition frequency of 600 Hz. The antenna
> rotates at a speed of 12° per second. Then the volume scan with the
> antenna pattern starts at 5.5° and turns down one degree after each
> further rotation. These scans use a pulse repetition frequency of 600
> or 800 Hz. The antenna rotation speed increases slightly to 18° per
> second, only the lowest diagram uses the 12° per second again
> (suppression of fixed clutter interference). In the eighth rotation,
> the scan is performed with an elevation angle of 8° and a pulse
> repetition frequency of 800 or 1 200 Hz. The elevation angles of 12°,
> 17°, and 25° use 2 410 Hz at a rotation speed of 30° per second.
> Finally, a scan is performed vertically upwards, which is used for
> internal calibration. The antenna aligns itself to the north and waits
> for the start of the next cycle. All precipitation radars of the DWD
> start simultaneously with the rotation for the next cycle. Therefore
> the rotation of the antennas is roughly synchronized and thus prevents
> the antennas from radiating each other. At the same time, it supports
> the formation of composite radar products (calculation of radar images
> from data of several radars), because the data from the precipitation
> scan, for example, are all from the same minute.

[image]

Comment: I think this is a good catch, +1. [VCP](https://wx.erau.edu/faculty/mullerb/Wx365/Volume_coverage_patterns/vcp.html) coverage has grown and changed over the years. But the quick reference table in the above link provides timing information for the tilts (cuts) used. And the OP may find a good fit there. Might be something else. But this hypothesis fits much of the observation shared with us.

Comment: The entire pattern of artifacts in my data lasts 255sec with a 60sec delay before it re-occurs, making 315sec or 5.25 min.  That's pretty close to the duration of VPCs 11/211 in the table provided by @periblepsis

Comment: Also it's kind of funny if it's a radar signal, because I used matched filtering to detect and remove the artifacts from my data.

Comment: @pnadeau Can you say what the strain gauges are measuring? Just curious.

Comment: I don't want to say too much, till publication, but they are attached to structure in a building.